# Como adicionar um buffer ao google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Segui vários tutoriais e um deles deu certo porém, quando compilo aparece o fragment normal com o nome google no canto inferior esquerdo da tela (normal), só que nada de mapa :( ... Quando estou em uma boa conexão com a internet ai as vezes da certo...(ah! fácil..o problema está na net!!!) bem.. acredito que não pois TODOS os apps que precisam de net carregam de booa até o google map ...só não o meu. Por esse fato, acredito que deve haver uma espécie de buffer para google map v2, se for o caso, alguém sabe como adaptar um buffer ao mapa?

---

Então...já está com todas as permissões adicionadas e o manifest está configurado conforme os diversos tutorias que eu vi...pesquisando, vi que meu problema pode n ser um buffer ou cach e sim uma API Key, que por sinal também está configurada como nos tutoriais, tinha que obter a Key por meio da SHA-1, no inicio fiz isso pela debug.keystore so que pretendo publicar o app então criei uma keystore privada e obtive a API Key, usei na aplicação conforme os tutoriais e continua apenas mostrando o nome google no canto inferior esquerdo e nada de mapa, no log vem a seguinte mensagem: Authentication failed. Timeout while trying to contact the server.

Answer (score 2):

Então o Google Maps para Android ele trabalha em cache logo quando você inicia ele faz isso automaticamente para você, mas lógico você tem que adicionar algumas permissões para ele poder fazer isso.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Essa é uma das principais para ele poder salvar no cache. Veja também como está configurando seu manifest se está tudo correto.

Doc do Google:

> You must also request the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Segue o link [Google Maps Android Configuração](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config)

Comment: obs: A partir do play services 8.3 esta permissão não é mais necessária